# C# Selected Overload Method On Runtime

Tags: c#, inheritance, exception, overloading

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class BaseException : Exception
    {
        public BaseException() { }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void MethodA(BaseException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BaseException");
        }

        public static void MethodA(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception");
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new BaseException();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
                MethodA(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hello guys i have one question according to the results of the above executed code :

e.GetType() == Rextester.BaseException

MethodA writes to console : Exception

So even though the Type of the exception is the derived class why in the run time is not called the specific overloaded method that has as parameter the BaseException and is called the one with Exception ?

Comment: Your question is not clear . Please add more description

Comment: Idk what is not clear here :o

Answer (score 3):

At the following try/catch block:

```
try
{
    throw new BaseException();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
    MethodA(e);
}
```

an exception is thrown and at the catch the type of the exception is `Exception`, not `BaseException`. You basically, throw and a `BaseException`, but `BaseException` inherits `Exception`. So you get into the catch block.

If you wanted to catch the `BaseException` you should catch this first, since it's more specific.

```
try
{
    throw new BaseException();
}
catch (BaseException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
    MethodA(e);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
    MethodA(e);
}
```

By the way, it is more clear the name `DerivedException` than the name `BaseException`. All exception types in .NET as well as the custom exception types, those that we define for our needs inherit from the `Exception` class. So all of them are derived classes of the class `Exception`.

The above can also be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/) as below:

> Exceptions have the following properties:
>
> - Exceptions are types that all **ultimately** derive from System.Exception.
> - Once an exception occurs in the try block, the flow of control jumps **to the first associated exception handler** that is present
>     anywhere in the call stack. In C#, the catch keyword is used to define
>     an exception handler.

In addition to the above, you would find helpful the content of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/exception-handling), where it stated that

> Multiple catch blocks with different exception filters can be chained together. 
>   **The catch blocks are evaluated from top to bottom in your code**, but
>   only one catch block is executed for each exception that is thrown.
>   The first catch block that specifies the exact type or a base class of
>   the thrown exception is executed. If no catch block specifies a
>   matching exception filter, a catch block that does not have a filter
>   is selected, if one is present in the statement. **It is important to**
>   **position catch blocks with the most specific (that is, the most**
>   **derived) exception types first**.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Exceptions. The thing is that overloaded methods are bound at _compile_ time.

Comment: @N73k I disagree with your statement. The reason is that the overloaded method that is going to be called it depends on the type the exception is caught. This is actually what I am trying to explain also in my answer, possibly not too well. I have written _an exception is thrown and at the catch the type of the exception is `Exception`, not `BaseException`_. That mean correctly as you said that the overloaded method `MethodA(Exception e)` would be called. So they way that the caller handles the thrown exception affects at compile time which would be the method that would be bound.

Comment: The thing is that the question is not specific to this try-catch-exception thing. The problem is more general than that. It happens not just with try-catch-exception stuff, but everywhere.

Comment: How else could you explain this *without* taking into account the handling of exception at all. I think that this is impossible, because even if you start talking about overloaded methods are bound at the compile time -which is definitely correct-, you can't explain how that works in this case _without starting from the type of exceptions_ and how they are handled. Honestly, I would appreciate if you could provide an explanation of this very specific case _without talking at all about exceptions_.

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded methods are bound at compile time.
At compile time, `e` has type `Exception`.
That's the reason.

It doesn't matter if the method is static or not. It's compile-time for both.

But after you catch the Exception you can do

```
dynamic dynEx = e;
MethodA(dynEx);
```

And you will get the right method called.

Answer (score 0):

The function `MethodA` is declared as static. Hence any binding to function is at compile time.